# Blender 3: rigging a trailer

Tags: rigging, constraints

I've been searching for a way to get a trailer rig, but the solutions I found are bullet physics method I can't find and a way using IK that's not clear at all.

Anybody has a clearest solution (please, no addons)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does anyone know how to rig a truck/trailer so that the trailer follows the truck in a realistic way?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81872/does-anyone-know-how-to-rig-a-truck-trailer-so-that-the-trailer-follows-the-truc)

Comment: Thanks, Chris, that's one of the solutions I found but it's a bit cryptic for me... not sure what is foot or shin in that gif.

Comment: it would help if you would have written that into your question that this didn't help... ;) i try it myself...

Comment: Ok, I'll keep in mind next time

Comment: ok, you are right...the description isn't really good ;) sorry for that

Comment: Nothing to apologize for :) . It looks a nice solution but without details we miss a lot of info

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19675/creating-a-trailer-rig/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81872/how-to-rig-a-truck-trailer-so-that-the-trailer-follows-the-truck/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it using this link https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/81979/105723

that cryptic solution mentioned above... I have to try and try till to make it work, since the elements in that answer haven't the same names in the explanation than the picture. This is my outliner with the structure:

[image: Armature and constraints]

Basically, as you see,  the head is the truck bone, the "neck" bone shouldn't be applied to mesh (just help the other bones to get the result) and a trailer bone. The named foot bone and target bone don't affect any mesh, just to control the IK chain with those constraints (copy rot and copy loc).

[image]

The blend file
[image]