# How i can make the trailer follow the truck realistically?

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

i make the truck follow path and make the trailer child of the truck to follow it but when i came to animate it it look fake not realistic like real world [image]

Comment: I think we need an example or more clarification.

Comment: i would try to use physics... ;)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81872/how-to-rig-a-truck-trailer-so-that-the-trailer-follows-the-truck  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19675/creating-a-trailer-rig https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41235/how-to-make-rig-that-reacts-to-gravity-or-seem-to-behave-physically-correct