I’m attempting to rig a wheel chair model. But I’m having issues with making the front wheels fuction as in when rotating to reverse & back to forward
The two front wheels are Childs of empties that are circles around the center of each wheel (x rotation).
Each of the empties, are Childs of circle empties that are flat (z rotation), which are supposed to control the rotation of each wheel separately.
Both also are constraints to a pivot empty that is located in the center of both for (Z rotation).
And the pivot is child of an empty for the left and right turning of the front wheels.
I have a driver to control the movements of each tire when going forward or backward… But that’s only in a straight line. Things begin to go funky when I turn, or turn in reverse… I want to know there is a way that I can make the back wheels kinda control the movement, and have the front wheel react as though they are being turned into the direction that the wheel chair is moving in.
I’m not sure if I’m making any sense here. But if anyone can help… I’ll be sure to accredit you for your help. Thank you for your time and consideration.

Do these answer your question? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19675/creating-a-trailer-rig https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81872/how-to-rig-a-truck-trailer-so-that-the-trailer-follows-the-truck/81979#81979
